# VS2010 F# Smart Tag to add open import declarations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, f#, smart-tags

**EDITS** corrected terminology from Intellisense to Smart Tag

OK, I readily admit that Intellisense/Smart Tags have spoiled me.  I've grown accustomed C# in Visual Studio notifying you to add **using** import declarations when typing in a class name for a namespace that has not yet been imported.  You get the nice little colored underscore which you can hover over or do or do ctrl-dot to get the context menu for adding the import or fully qualifying the namespace.

I've just started playing with F# in VS2010, and I'm not getting that helpful reminder when I reference a system library class.  I type **WebRequest** and the Smart Tag doesn't kick in to tell me I need to add an **open System.Net** declaration.

Am I missing something?  Is there a VS extension available that beefs up F# Smart Tagging?

Comment: I always forget to open a suggestion on MS Connect about this. If you do, please post the link here so we can vote it.

Comment: Here it is: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/570482/f-smart-tag-for-adding-import-declarations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two features here.  Intellisense is the feature that helps complete statements and expressions as you type.  The squiggle that appears over `WebRequest` to tell you that you need to add a using / open for `System.Net` is a smart tag.

F# unfortunately does not implement this particular smart tag in Visual Studio 2010.  I don't know of any extension which provides this behavior either.

Comment: Do you have a sense for how hard it would be to write such an extension?  Is it something that people outside of the F#/VS teams could build?

Comment: @kvb, Without access to the f# compiler it would probably be fairly difficult because it requires semantic knowledge of the situation.

Comment: I bet you could build a cheesy version with less effort, using the compiler as a black box and looking for `The namespace or module '%s' is not defined` (along with line/column info) in the Error List, and using DTE to enumerate the referenced assemblies in the project.

Comment: @Brian, that would probably work very well indeed.   Why haven't you done that yet ;)

Comment: Noted, thanks for the correction.  I've updated the title and question with the correct terminology